# Incredibly slow performance with this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am getting incredibly slow performance when executing this query,

i cannot see anything obvious,can any one suggest me the best way to get through it

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_NominalPurchase (    
    NomCode varchar(16),    
    NomDesc varchar(61),    
    GoodsSold money 
) 

declare @Pos Int 
select @Pos = 1 
while @Pos <= (select max(dbo.fn_DCount(NValues,'~')) from pledger) 
begin   
    INSERT INTO #tmp_NominalPurchase    (NomCode, NomDesc, GoodsSold)    (       
    select 
        a.keyCode NomCode, 
        a.descr NomDesc,
        sum(convert(money, dbo.fn_Field(pl.NValues,'~', @Pos)   )) GoodsSold
    from pledger pl  
    inner join accts a 
        On  dbo.fn_Field(pl.NCodes,'~', @Pos) = a.keycode
        and (acctType='N' and pb='P' and category='cs')         
    where convert(datetime, pl.batch) >='2014-01-01' 
      and convert(datetime, pl.batch) <'2014-06-25'        
    group by a.keyCode, a.descr)   

    select @Pos = @Pos + 1 
end 

select o.* FROM
(
    select t.NomCode,
        t.NomDesc, 
        0 GoodsCost,
        0 GoodsDisc, 
        sum(t.GoodsSold) GoodsSold, 
        '24/06/2014 05:01:14 PM' as LocalDateAndTime 
    from #tmp_NominalPurchase t  
    group by 
        t.NomCode,
        t.NomDesc 
) o 
Order By o.NomCode Asc 

DROP TABLE #tmp_NominalPurchase
```

Comment: What piece is slow?  The insert or the select?  Have you done an explain?  And what's with the while loop?

Comment: Don't use a while loop. Use Set based logic.

Comment: Doing something inside a while loop seems like a slow me down.

Comment: You are using while loops, you have function inside select sub-query, you have function in join condition, you are converting in where condition... You have done almost every possible thing that should be avoided. Each of those can slow your query a lot.

Comment: How many times is the while loop executing? If you remove the insert Into clause and just execute the select statement does the speed improve substantially? How many rows are in the relevant tables?

Comment: Why use a temporary table? Why one without indices?

Comment: If you insist on using a while loop, at least start with your query count and work back to one, rather than re-running that query at each iteration.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you'll get best results if you fix your broken pledger.NValues column. _This should really be it's own table_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No rewritten query and performance has increased majorly, this has reduced the query runtime from 12 seconds to < 1 second

- added a function to get the count
- SQL rewritten to use the count

**The Improved SQL**

```
SELECT dbo.fn_Field(pl.NValues,'~',1) AS [nVals1], dbo.fn_Field(pl.Ncodes,'~',1)  as [nCodes1], dbo.fn_Field(pl.NValues,'~',2)  as [nVals2], dbo.fn_Field(pl.Ncodes,'~',2)  as [nCodes2],
       'x' AS x INTO #tmp_NominalPurchase
FROM pledger pl
WHERE convert(datetime, pl.batch) >='2014-06-01'
  AND convert(datetime, pl.batch) <'2014-06-28'
  SELECT a.keycode AS NomCode,
         a.descr AS NomDesc,
         max(0) AS goodsCost,
         max(0) AS GoodsDisc,
         sum(CAST (NValue AS money)) AS GoodsSold ,
         '06/27/2014 11:44:47 AM' AS LocalDateAndTime
  FROM
    (SELECT [nVals1] AS NValue,[nCodes1] AS NCode
     FROM dbo.#tmp_NominalPurchase tnp
     UNION ALL SELECT [nVals2]AS NValue,[nCodes2] AS NCode
     FROM dbo.#tmp_NominalPurchase tnp) x
  INNER JOIN dbo.Accts a ON x.Ncode = a.keycode
  AND acctType='N'
  AND category='cs'
  AND pb='P'
GROUP BY a.keycode,
         a.descr
ORDER BY NomCode
DROP TABLE #tmp_NominalPurchase
```

**Function to get count**

```
Public Function getNCodeCount(ByVal sWhere) As Integer '00528591

 Dim Ds As DataSet
 Dim sqlSb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
 Dim nCodesCount As Integer = 0
 sqlSb.Append("SELECT isnull(max(dbo.fn_DCount(NValues,'~')),0) FROM PLEDGER PL with (nolock)" & sWhere)

 Ds = SqlConnect.SqlNet.OpenSQLdataset(sqlSb.ToString)
 If Ds Is Nothing Then GoTo report_failed
 If Ds.Tables.Count < 1 Then
  GoTo report_failed
 End If
 With Ds.Tables(0)
  For Each r In .Rows
    nCodesCount = r(0)
  Next
 End With
Return nCodesCount

Exit Function
 report_failed:
  Return 0

        '00528591 END

    End Function
```

**Function to build the SQL string and output the report**

```
    Public Function LedgerNominalListingReportPurchase(ByVal DateFrom As String, ByVal DateTo As String, ByVal SortType As String, Optional ByVal DetailReport As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal NominalCode As String = "") As DataView 'L754303 (163.47)
            Dim sql As String = ""
            Dim gs As New GeneralSQL
            Dim aWhere As New ArrayList
            Dim sWhere As String = ""

            If IsDate(DateFrom) Then aWhere.Add("convert(datetime, pl.batch) >=" & gs.SqlDate(CDate(DateFrom)))
            If IsDate(DateTo) Then aWhere.Add("convert(datetime, pl.batch) <" & gs.SqlDate(CDate(DateTo).AddDays(1)))

            For Each s As String In aWhere
                If sWhere = "" Then
                    sWhere &= " where "
                Else
                    sWhere &= " and "
                End If
                sWhere &= s
            Next

            If Not DetailReport Then 'L754303 (163.47)

                'NEW SQL (FASTER) 00528591

                sql &= "SELECT max(dbo.fn_DCount(NValues,'~')) FROM PLEDGER"

                Dim nCodeCount As Integer = (getNCodeCount(sWhere))

                If nCodeCount = Nothing Or 0 Then

                    sql = "CREATE TABLE #tmp_NominalPurchase (NomCode varchar(16), NomDesc varchar(61), GoodsCost money, GoodsDisc money, GoodsSold money) SELECT * FROM #tmp_NominalPurchase DROP TABLE #tmp_NominalPurchase"

                Else

                    Dim qCount As Integer = 1


                    sql = "SELECT "

                    While qCount <= nCodeCount

                        sql &= "dbo.fn_Field(pl.NValues,'~'," + qCount.ToString
                        sql &= ") "
                        sql &= " as [nVals" + qCount.ToString
                        sql &= "], "

                        sql &= "dbo.fn_Field(pl.Ncodes,'~'," + qCount.ToString
                        sql &= ") "
                        sql &= " as [nCodes" + qCount.ToString
                        sql &= "], "

                        qCount += 1

                    End While

                    sql &= " 'x' as x "
                    sql &= "INTO  #tmp_NominalPurchase FROM pledger pl " & sWhere

                    sql &= "SELECT a.keycode as NomCode, a.descr as NomDesc,max(0) AS goodsCost,max(0) AS GoodsDisc, sum(cast (NValue AS money) ) AS GoodsSold "
                    sql &= String.Format(", '{0}' as LocalDateAndTime", Format(General.UserNow, vars.Ses.FmtDate & " " & "hh:mm:ss tt")) 'V759658 (163.31) - format the date column based on the CountryMode setting
                    sql &= " FROM ("

                    sql &= "SELECT [nVals1] AS NValue,[nCodes1] AS NCode FROM dbo.#tmp_NominalPurchase tnp "
                    qCount = 2

                    While qCount <= nCodeCount
                        sql &= " UNION all "
                        sql &= "SELECT [nVals" + qCount.ToString
                        sql &= "]AS NValue,[nCodes" + qCount.ToString
                        sql &= "] AS NCode FROM dbo.#tmp_NominalPurchase tnp"



                        qCount += 1

                    End While

                    sql &= ") x inner join dbo.Accts a on x.Ncode = a.keycode and acctType='N' AND category='cs'  AND pb='P' group by a.keycode,a.descr "
                    sql &= "ORDER BY " & SortType
                    sql &= " DROP TABLE #tmp_NominalPurchase"



                End If
            End If

 Return SqlConnect.SqlNet.OpenSQLdataset(sql).Tables(0).DefaultView '00529265 

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing I see is you are converting pl.batch to a string before you do the comparison in the where clause. That would defeat any indices that might prevent a table scan.

You are also doing a join on a user defined function fn_field. Not knowing the purpose of that function, I'm wondering if that is creating an issue. When I see things like that, I suspect it's there because the data schema isn't well thought out.

Comment: Looks like he's using the function to break apart ~-delimited data. Moving that data out to it's own table or set of columns here would also go a long way towards improving performance.